# Passing simple unique id's for my users and products

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a model in my application for users and products . I want to create a unique id in the database which is by order of creation eg 1 , 2, 3

More like a unique id bt based on count like each user or product is created it gets a unique id bt either 1 or 2 increasing upto even thousands Increasing from the last number

Comment: The following blog post discusses: [Generating Globally Unique Identifiers for Use with MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb). See sub-topic **Use a single counter document to generate unique identifiers one at a time** which may be of interest to you.